# Approximate Killing vector field in general relativity

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, vector-fields

In this  [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0602001) the authors consider an approximate Killing field $\chi$. It vanishes on a given 2 surface and its first order part is given.They say that if it obeys the Killing equation $\chi_{a;b}+\chi_{b;a} = 0 $ then its second order part vanishes.
Do you understand why?

Answer (score 1):

Zhen Lin shows [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94440/a-question-about-killing-vector-and-riemann-curvature-tensor)  that
if a vector field $\chi$ obeys the Killing' equation $\chi^i_{;j} +\chi^j_{;i} = 0 $ then $\chi^a_{;bc} = R^a_{;bcd} \chi^d $everywhere.
As $\chi$ vanishes at p, we have at this point $\chi^a_{;bc} = 0. $
The second order part of the taylor serie being quadratic in the covariant derivatives, it equals zero.
Raf Guedens who is a co-author of the initial paper gives many details in (https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0542)